# amcharts integration with django

Tags: django, django-views, amcharts

I need to display data from HttpResponse as charts.(xaxis = datetime , yaxis is an aggregate stat function).I succeeded to export the data into a csv file.How can I integrate django with amcharts?

```
def monitor(request):   
    if request.method == 'POST' :
    forms = ServicesForm(request.POST)
    if forms.is_valid():
        service = forms.cleaned_data['service']
        scale = forms.cleaned_data['scale']
        datatype = forms.cleaned_data['datatype']
        starttime = forms.cleaned_data['starttime']
        endtime = forms.cleaned_data['endtime']

        db_table = u'servicestats'
        name = Servicenames.objects.get(servicename=service)

        servicestats = Servicestats.objects.raw('SELECT distinct dtime,scale,' + datatype + ' FROM ' + db_table + ' WHERE scale = ' + str(scale) + ' AND dtime BETWEEN "' + str(starttime) + '" AND "' + str(endtime) + '" AND service_id = ' + str(name.id))  
        response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv') 
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename="export.csv"'         
        writer = csv.writer(response)
        for s in servicestats:
            if datatype =='cnt':
                writer.writerow([s.dtime,s.cnt])
            if datatype =='avg' :
                writer.writerow([s.dtime,s.avg])
            if datatype =='min' :
                writer.writerow([s.dtime,s.min])
            if datatype =='max' :
                writer.writerow([s.dtime,s.max])  
            if datatype =='threenines' :
                writer.writerow([s.dtime,s.threenines])   
        return response

else:
    forms =  ServicesForm


return render_to_response('monitor/monitor.html', {'forms':forms},
   context_instance = RequestContext(request)) 

template,html :
 <form action='/monitor/' method="post"> {%csrf_token%}
    {{ forms.as_p}}
    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">    
</form>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.  It looks like your monitor view is intended to act like a restful interface where the post to the form returns a csv file? Where is your amchart stuff?

Comment: This is my question.I returned a csv file to test my queries.I need to return amchart graph.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you already have the Django part working.  Now you need to feed this into the amcharts javascript renderer on the client side.  See this [blog article](http://blog.amcharts.com/2011/03/amcharts-javascript-tutorials-part-2.html) for how to do this.  You need to replace the data.txt with your url:

```
    window.onload = function() {
        loadCSV("data.txt");
    }
```

and modify the loadCSV from a get to a post to your view above:

```
    function loadCSV(file) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            var request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }
        // load
        request.open('GET', file, false);
        request.send();
        parseCSV(request.responseText);
    }
```

A quick google provides [this page](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php) for how to modify that request.open to use post instead.

Comment: Should I download and unzip amcharts into my django project?

Comment: Yes.  You'll need to load their javascript.  Not sure if they have a globally available download link but I always host my own of these.

Comment: What do you mean by "I always host my own of these" ?

Comment: Sorry,  "host my own copy of these types of files".  eg. I don't get jquery from google, I get host it myself.

Comment: How can I write in the view the httpresponse part to send the relevant data to the JS HTML file ?I am new to Django.

Comment: You already have!  You need to modify the loadCSV javascript function to post to your url rather than the get that is currently there.

Comment: I meant that there is a way to pass the data directly from the view to javascript-flash client without the csv file.How to do it?HttpResponse  in the view and html javascript flash file. How?

Comment: Ah.  I'll answer this in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using this [blog article](http://blog.amcharts.com/2011/03/amcharts-javascript-tutorials-part-2.html) as a base you are going to replace the data with an array generated in the javascript file.  Essentially do this in your new template:

```
var dataprovider = [
{% for s in servicestats %}
       {date:s.dtime, value1:s.cnt, value2:s.min **more values here**}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

];

And pass servicestats into that template.

Comment: How do I pass servicestats in the view for the javascript template?

Comment: In other words , do I need to send from the django view HTTPresponseredirect with the servicestats data to the html javascript template? how do I write this passing in the view?

Comment: By the way , it seems to me that it would be better to pass the dtime and other data values already retrieved in the view and not the queryset servicestats.How should I write it in my view ? Thanks.

Comment: use {'form': form, 'serverstats': servicestats} in the render_to_response instead of returning a csv

Comment: What form? The form is only used if there is no POST request (before the POST request).